# Cannot import from my custom python package. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'a_python_file_inside_my_custom_module'

Tags: python, package, init, python-packaging, modulenotfounderror

I am trying to build a python package following [this tutorial](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/build-your-first-python-package/).

So I have made a base folder, then a module folder, then inside it I have placed the file starting_template.py, which contains the function `load_img` and a `__init__.py` file whose content is barely

```
from starting_template import load_img
print("loaded!")
```

If I manually run `__init__.py`, it works without showing any error, it prints "loaded!".

So this is the directory tree:

[image]

I have built the package by running

```
python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
```

in the base directory, then I have uploaded the package on my pypi account by running

```
twine upload dist/opencv_auxiliary_for_vscode-0.0.2*
```

where `0.0.2` is the version number of the distribution,
and finally installed the module by running

```
pip install opencv_auxiliary_for_vscode==0.0.2
```

The package is uploaded [here](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-auxiliary-for-vscode/0.0.2/).
It is a lame code, but it is just to practice the process of building python packages.

Then, in a python file, I wrote the import statement

```
from opencv_auxiliary_for_vscode import load_img
```

but as I run it, I get the error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'starting_template'
```

I have also tried to import

```
from opencv_auxiliary_for_vscode.starting_template import load_img
```

but it does not work.

What am I possibly doing wrong?

Comment: `from .starting_template` - with dot, to show it's local import. When you don't have the dot, it tries to find starting_template in standard and installed packages. It worked before because you run the code as code, not as module, and current directory is always added to PATH

Comment: Thanks @h4z3 it worked, if you wish you can write an answer and I will flag it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated by @h4z3, I had to change the content of `__init__.py` from

```
from starting_template import load_img
print("loaded!")
```

to

```
from .starting_template import load_img  # with the dot
print("loaded!")
```

to show it is a local import.

> When you don't have the dot, it tries to find `starting_template` in
> standard and installed packages.

> It ( running `__init__.py` ) worked
> before because you run the code as code, not as module, and current
> directory is always added to PATH

Also I had to increment by `0.0.1` the `VERSION` variable in `setup.py` every time I made a new attempt to re-upload the module

```
python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel

twine upload dist/opencv_auxiliary_for_vscode-0.0.3*
# __token__
# PyPI api key

pip install opencv_auxiliary_for_vscode==0.0.3
```